# Doubling each word or number combination in a String

Tags: java, string, char

I'm trying to get each word and/or number/symbol combination input in a string doubled in this way:

```
My name is >> My My name name is is
148 !! 697 >> 148 148 !! !! 697 697
The code is 428 >>  The The code code is is 428 428
```

I've spent a while with this and I just can't seem to figure out how to get the doubling to work properly or keep the doubled parts separated from one another.

Answer (score 3):

Using, a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), you can do this quite simply. The following [groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) all characters that aren't whitespace (`\S`) and replaces them by themselves twice, using the back-reference `$1`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str = { "My name is", "148 !! 697", "The code is 428" };
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)");
    for (String s : str) {
        String res = pattern.matcher(s).replaceAll("$1 $1");
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

This prints

```
My My name name is is
148 148 !! !! 697 697
The The code code is is 428 428
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String phrase = "My name is";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(String word : phrase.split(" ")) {
    result.append(word).append(" ").append(word).append(" ");
}

String finalResult = result.toString().trim(); //trim() removes the last, extraneous space.
```

Comment: Using `StringJoiner` (Java 8), you don't need to remove the last spurious space.

Answer (score 0):

Loop though the string and for each word append it two times to a new mutable string.

Answer (score 0):

By word, I assume you mean space-separated item?

```
String doubleit(String inpString) {
    List<String> doubles = new ArrayList<String>();
    String [] items = inpString.split();
    for ( String item : items ) {
        doubles.add( item );
        doubles.add( item );
    }
    return doubles.join( " " );
}
```